# org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage option not appearing when i try to extend WebPage

Tags: eclipse, wicket

I am trying to create a "Hello World" Wicket Application.
When I try to create a HelloWorldPage.java file, I do not get 'org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage' option for"SuperClass" option.

How do i fix this?

I am using Eclipse Luna IDE and have Apache Tomcat 8.0.14

Comment: Did you add the necessary jars to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

here you find projects for the Wicket user guide, including an HelloWorldExample:
https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples

To import Maven-based projects in eclipse you can use Maven integration plugin:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-luna#.VF__o4WFvFY

Once you have installed this plugin you will find "Import Maven project" in the import menu.